# Phpstorm shows all files are changed, when non has changed (using git)

Tags: php, git, phpstorm

me and my colleague are working on the same project but we use different platforms,
I use MAC, and he uses PC.

The issue is when one of us preforms a commit to our local repository, we have configured our git to auto_crlf input on MAC and true on PC.

and still, When I (using MAC) open the project after it was committed using the PC I see all the files blue colored (changed) when the changes are only on the line endings or white-spaces.

The same happens when I (using MAC) committing the project and he (using PC) opens it.

All I want is that the true changes will be shown and not the line-endings ones, is it possible to make it work that way? I've truly looked everywhere, and didnt find any good solution for this issue.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that everyone in your team saves their line endings in the same format.

This can be changed in the settings like in the screenshot below (line settings ending):

[image: PHPStorm line endings setting]

Comment: This option is for newly created file only. But yes -- definitely correct way to go (in general). Next step (after this) would be converting all line endings to be the same for all files on all platforms (choosing `\n` would be the best as it works the same on Windows, Linux and Mac).

Comment: @swifty, your solution didn't work for me, we both set the line endings to be \n, tried on some new files and still they are shown as changed, while there is no difference now between them.